# Client side image resize and ftp component

Tags: image, ftp, resize, client

I am looking for a component that resizes and ftp's images to a website.
It doesn't have to be free.
In fact, I prefer something we pay for that comes with solid support.

It has to be able to transfer multiple images at once too.

We work in an ASP.NET MVC environment but the component could be in Flash or Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [Aurigma Image Uploader](http://www.aurigma.com/Products/ImageUploader/) successfully in the past. However it doesn't support ftp'ing the uploaded files out of the box, but this could be easily done from the web server end ...

Answer (score 0):

I've used imagemagick and netpbm. Both do excellent job of image manipulation. Since you didn't mention any language, I assume that you will use some kind of script to do both conversion and transfer. I would get everything resized first, and then ftp'ing (or scp, which is simpler to script)

Comment: I am looking for a client side component in Flash/Silverlight/anything else that automatically does these things and then ftp's the reduced images to a website not a generic library.

Answer (score 0):

Most are standalone vs. components, but might find something that fits the needs:

http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Best/ftp-resize.html